# Not moving through Objects in a whole 3D Model AFRAME

Tags: javascript, aframe

I have a whole 3D .glb Model of a house with walls. If I have a single object I can use static body to prevent camera going through the objects, Since I have a whole 3D Model, what would be the proper way to prevent going through walls.

```
<a-scene physics="debug:true">
        <a-assets>
            <a-asset-item id="3dmodel" src="videos/house.glb"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>

        <a-entity camera look-controls wasd-controls position="0 1.6 0">
            <a-cursor></a-cursor>
        </a-entity>

        <a-entity gltf-model="#3dmodel"></a-entity>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: use my solution to this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71979173/preventing-the-camera-entering-entities-in-a-frame/72011148#72011148

Comment: I'm still being able to move through the objects.

Comment: are you using networked aframe?

Comment: No, I don't use that.

Comment: can you share detailed code via glitch?

Comment: Actually, I quite understand about nav mesh right now and thank you for the reference!